# File "A.gitgnore" is not ignoring files

Tags: git, gitignore

I made a gitignore file called `A.gitignore` in my repo's root directory to ignore `.dbf` files and anything in a subdirectory called `NFIRS`.
The gitignore content is two lines:

```
*.dbf
NFIRS/
```

Now I committed and pushed this gitignore. After committing and pushing, whenever I make a `.dbf` file such as `test.dbf` in the root directory (filenames that have *never* been committed) GitHub Desktop still wants to track and commit this new file. `git add .` in a terminal window also fails to implement the gitignore. It also does not ignore newly created sub-dirs called `NFIRS` (after ensuring any previous tracking is cleared).

I've tried multiple times in terminal in the root directory:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "test"
```

and this does not fix the issue (so again, not the simple issue of .gitignore ignoring previously tracked files)

I'm a little at a loss for how .gitignore is supposed to work.

Comment: The file should be called literally `.gitignore`. In other words: `.gitignore` is **not** the file extension, it's the whole file name.

Comment: .gitignore is a hiddenfile its not an extension like MP3 or something the file name should be .gitignore not like abc.gitigone or sometiing

Comment: I see. So I had tried this previously but Mac OSX will not allow it to be renamed that in Finder. I got around it by saving it through Textmate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.gitignore` isn't an extension - it's the exact name you should use (following the POSIX convention that a file starting with a `.` is a hidden file).

`A.gitignore` has no special meaning in Git, and as you have seen, Git doesn't ignore the files listed in it.